# How to reference element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, this

I am currently teaching myself jQuery (started yesterday) and I'm stuck already.. I have this to create small dropdowns that will work relative to each other.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var selTxt = 0;
  $(".button").click(function(){
        alert($(this).prev(".button").attr("id"));
        $(".text").slideUp(150);
        $(this).next(".text").slideToggle(150,function(){
            selTxt = $(this).prev(".button").attr("id");
        });

  });
});
```

Those of you that know jQuery will realise it simply expands a textbox when clicking a button and hides all others that are expanded.

**Question:**

Take a look and see where the `alert()` function is called. On that line I wish to run an if statement.. Something like this:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr("id") == selTxt){
        $(".text").slideUp(150);
        $(this).next(".text").slideToggle(150,function(){
            selTxt = $(this).prev(".button").attr("id");
        });
    }
});
```

Hence I only want it to run if `selTxt` doesn't equal the `id` of the element that has been clicked. So the $(this) in the if statement (I HOPED) would refer to the `.button` being clicked, but guess what: it doesn't! Could anybody inform me why not? I thought because I referenced the `.button` with $(this) lower down that I would be able to use it there as well but evidently not.

Good old JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/A4eHC/).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The way i test this is like, give the button and id lets say id="pressed" and after $(".button").click(function(){ alert($(this).attr("id")); }); and see if corrosponds? if not then maybe you forgot to ask the class?

Comment: $(this) in this context is the element with class button that was clicked. If you do console.log($(this)); doesn't it log out the correct element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Hawiak pointed, the problem is that your're testing `.attr("id")` of all `div.button` but your HTML has an `id` attribute assigned only for the first `div`. But at all, I don't believe checking by the `id` is the best way to do it. Here's my suggestion:

```
$(function() {
  $(".button").click(function() {
      var text = $(this).next(".text");

      if (!text.hasClass("open")) {
        $(".text").slideUp(150).removeClass("open");
        text.stop(true, true).slideToggle(150).addClass("open");
      }
  });

  $(".hideAll").click(function() {
    $(".text").slideUp(150).removeClass("open");
  });
});​
```

And the updated Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/A4eHC/4/).

Comment: Where are these `open` and `close` classes coming from are they part of the jQuery library? In fact I don't completely understand your changes, could you possible give some explaination? I'd really appreciate!

Comment: Using classes to control elements' "state" with jQuery is a common practice. Since we are not changing any style when toggling, using a class that isn't at the CSS is not a problem. This way, the `.text` keeps itself the information about being opened or closed.

Comment: OK so we're basically using the `class` attribute as a variable? Thanks you've been a great help.

Comment: Yes, this is it. Of course, we could do the same thing using `.data()`. Do it the way you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

It does work, in your JSfiddle you've only added an ID to the first DIV element and not to all the others, therefor a UNDIFINED will show up if you try to get the ID attr from the element, so add the ids and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I've only added an ID to the first element but I'm only testing the first element.

Comment: I've changed your JS to this http://jsfiddle.net/A4eHC/3/ If you click the first one it does show the ID of that element doesnt it ;)